# Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect. How to get a HD profile picture while login

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using new sign in with linkeIn using OpenID.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2

Anyone has any idea that with new sign in method.how can i get HD profile picture while sign in with linkeIn? now it is coming 100x100 image by using API - GET **https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo**

I have found out profile picture API. which requires to call API
**GET [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection(id,profilePicture(displayImage~digitalmediaAsset:playableStreams))](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection(id,profilePicture(displayImage%7EdigitalmediaAsset:playableStreams)))**

But i have not able to figure out how to get access to **/me** endpoint.

I am not able to figure out how to get HD profile picture while fetching user profile after sign in with linkedIn.

I want HD profile picture.

Thank you in advance for your help & advice.